# Retina Macbook pro freezes when Notification centre is triggered

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, notifications

Okay, so this is a really weird error. Every so often when I trigger the notification centre using the two finger swipe, the machine will freeze. The notification centre can't be dismissed and any action I try to do after that just doesn't work. I can select some things like in the status bar and can even choose to go to login screen but the action does not complete, i.e I can only see a blank screen after that and not the login window.

This is irritating because it does not happen every time and is completely random as far as I can tell.

The only thing I can do after this happens is restart. I'm completely at a loss as to what might cause this as this does not seem to be a common error. A Google search hasn't revealed much.

This has been happening for quite some time and I don't recall installing any specific app after which this started happening. Maybe Better Touch Tool but there's no real connection I can make out.

Retina Macbook Pro on Mountain Lion with all available updates applied.

Comment: Did you find any information on your Mac Console (in Applications/Utilities) after your hard reboot ? I see Better Touch deals with gesture so that can be indeed your problem. Is this software up to date ? You can try to take a look in Better Touch Tool logs too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is I can remember this happening before I had BTT installed. How do I check Better Touch Tool logs? Through console only?

Comment: you can try the console or check if BTT has a folder on your disk where logs for the app are. You can also try to uninstall BTT for some time and see if the problem disappear.

Comment: I remember it happened when BTT wasn't installed. And it has happened once when I've clicked on NC's icon. I'll wait for it to happen another time and put see the console. Should I post the post reboot console log here?

Comment: Yeah you can join it to your question. The extreme answer would be to backup your data and reinstall OS X but maybe the console log will help